# Xapo api tutorials

Tags: api, website-integration, faucets

I am building a website and wish to have a deposit bitcoin widget on website.
I want to have xapo api to generate new address and get callbacks from it.

Can someone please help me figuring out the xapo's api.

I read its documentation over 10 times and still cannot find out that how to integrate it with php.

Please help me on it.
EDIT

By Deposit widget I meant the deposit page, how it generates new addresses and gets the notification of payment received by a specific user.

Link to xapo api documentation.
http://docs.xapo.apiary.io

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by deposit widget? Can you provide more info on what you are trying to accomplsih?

Comment: m1xolyd1an I viewed all your youtube tutorials and subscribed too. Please read the edit

Comment: A link to the xapo API documentation might be a better way to get responses IMO

Comment: I'm from Xapo. Please, contact us directly (developers@xapo.com) so we can better understand what you need to do.

Comment: @Yash Lotan did you get it to work ? Most requests work for me, but the create_address returns "bad request" error.

Comment: @adrianTNT Yes I made it to work and created a php package for the api. Link -> https://github.com/yash0212/xapo